# Why does my Gradle Build does not work with Lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently programming a Spring Boot Application and I want to use Lombok to make things easier.
When I try to perform the gradle build, I get the error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':checkLombokConfig'.
> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

The full error looks like this:

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at ...
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:352)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3399)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3436)
    at io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.tasks.CheckLombokConfig.check(CheckLombokConfig.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    ...

Root cause: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:352)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:178)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3399)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3436)
    at io.freefair.gradle.plugins.lombok.tasks.CheckLombokConfig.check(CheckLombokConfig.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    ...
```

My build file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '6.1.0-m3'    
}

group = 'de.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.6.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// Make implicit dependency explicit
startScripts {
    dependsOn(bootJar)
}

// Define the main class for the "gradle run" task
mainClassName = 'de.test.testApplication'

// Disable generation of zip and tar distributions. 
tasks.distZip.enabled = false
tasks.distTar.enabled = false
tasks.bootDistZip.enabled = false
tasks.bootDistTar.enabled = false
```

I can only run the project as "Spring Boot App" when I add the annotation processor manually in my IDE.
I am using SpringToolsSuite4 and Java 11 on Windows.

Does somebody know how I can fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}
```

in your `build.gradle` file